# Should I be using flash for this?

Tags: flash, animation

I am helping a friend with a website for her non-profit organization. The main page will be fairly simple, using standards compliant, semantic XHTML and CSS. My question revolves around a feature she wants to include.

She wants to have a section of the site with the letters that spell out the organization's name across the top. She wants it to cycle through these letters, and for the "active" letter it should highlight the letter and then change the display in the rest of the box to pertinent images/info. SO - imagine the name of the org is Example- the box would say:

E  X  A  M  P  L  E

across the top, and first the "E" would brighten or highlight, then the box would fill with text saying "E is for blah" with a link to blah. After 5 or 10 seconds, that would fade out, the "X" would highlight, and the box fills with "X is for fooblah", etc..., repeat ad nauseum.

I know I could easily do this in Flash, but I've always been wary of using Flash, especially for something like this which contains nav elements (although it is not the main site nav).

How would the more experienced web developers here attack this problem? Should I bite the bullet and use Flash, or look into other technologies? I'd love to not alienate iphone/ipad users, but I can always sniff for Flash player and display a static image or something instead.

Any advice is welcome and appreciated, and if it makes you feel any better, you helping this noob out is also helping a good cause.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go for a JavaScript approach for sure.

I never use Flash when things can be done with JavaScript.

I use the jQuery JavaScript library often lately to make life easier. :)

You should also be able to do it with 'pure' JavaScript though.

Check out jQuery @ http://www.jquery.com

Comment: I can setup an example if you like using the jQuery approach.

Comment: I'd love to see an example, that would be awesome!

Comment: I realize this was a stupid question to ask on SO...more opinion than anything else. However, I'm giving the answer to PeeHaa since it got me to take a closer look at jquery. I was able to code up something that fits the bill, is fluidly resizeable, and maintains accessibility without needing to test for flash player and display another image if flash is not installed. Also, works on iOS devices, which is a huge plus!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, a javascript implementation and Flash.

Since I'm a Flash developer I will chime in with some of the reasons you might want to use Flash.

- It will most definitely take less
  time.
- You have more animation options, and
  they will look cooler.
- It will run faster, and if you use
  vectors, be very light-weight.

If you want to do this in Flash, check out the timer class for AS3, and setInterval for AS2.

Comment: Also, do make sure that if you go with the flash route that you offer some way for users to access the linked content that doesn't rely on the swf.  There can be legal ramifications if a site is deemed "inaccessable" to people with disabilities.  Of course, simply using JS to make fancy animations doesn't automatically make a site "accessable" either, so it's not a black and white either/or proposition... so weigh the options carefully.

Comment: @scriptocalypse - good point! all the linked content in the swf will be available in other areas in the site - the purpose of the swf is to cycle through calls to action that the site owner wants to be "in your face" - things like a donation button, facebook link, etc... does having those available on other subpages or areas of the home page solve the accessibility issues?

Comment: thanks, nice to get an opinion from a flash dev. I've only messed around with flash a few times, so if I go that route I have some research ahead of me! When you mention using vectors, are you referring to vector graphics, or the vector class in AS3? Thanks for the reply!